# Lexical context of 'this' in Nested Object Literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm asking because I've read similar (but not equal) questions about this issue.

As far as I understand, I get why this code would **NOT** work:

```js
let myObj = {
  name: 'inner text',
  myFunction: () => {
    console.log("before text " + this.name + " after text");
  }
}
myObj.myFunction();
```

**Reason:** the context where the arrow function is created (`myObj`) belongs to the global scope (which is `window` or `undefined` depending on strict mode and so on).

I get that. But **in the case of nested object literals**, shouldn't be the outer object literal the inherited context for the arrow function like following example?

```js
let outer = {
  name: 'outer',
  obj: {
    name: 'inner',
    myFunction: () => {
      console.log("before text " + this.name + " after text");
    }
  }
}
outer.obj.myFunction();
```

I would expect that `this` refers to the context of `outer`, which is the object literal where `obj` is nested.
This is not the case and the reason I don't understand properly this inherited lexical scope.

Could someone throw some light about why is that happening?

Comment: The lexical scope is the same, only functions create scopes. Just don't use arrow functions as methods. Or if you necessarily want to do it, use an old good constructor function with `new`, then you will have an appropriate scope for the correct `this` value.

Comment: A scope is created based on function/constructor. So when you use an arrow function, the scope is associated of parent function and not object

Comment: If the values of normal object literals don't have a special `this` value, why would it be different for nested object literals?

Answer (score 2):

> But in the case of nested object literals, shouldn't be the outer object literal the inherited context for the arrow function like following example?

No.

An arrow function copies the **current** value of `this`;

```
var object = {
     a: this,
     b: { 
         a: this,
         b: {
             a: this
         }
     } 
}
```

It doesn't matter how many levels you nest it, the value of `this` doesn't change.

Since every level of the object literal appears in the same function, they all get the same `this` value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. The most compact could be to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) like follows:

```js
let outer = {
  name: 'outer',
  obj: {
    name: 'inner',
    get myFunction() {
      console.log("before text " + this.name + " after text");
      return (this.name);
    }
  }
}
outer.obj.myFunction;
```

Inside a getter/setter your context is guaranteed to be the object instance (the most nested) (remember that each inner object is an 'independent' instance of Object, and getters/setters will belong to the nearest instance).

The problem with your code is that your arrow function is preserving the execution context at the time of creating the object.

Another way to achieve the intended behaviour would be to save a manually bound method as follows:

```js
let outer = {
  name: 'outer',
  obj: {
    name: 'inner'
  }
}
outer.obj.myFunction = (function () {console.log("before text " + this.name + " after text");}).bind(outer.obj);
outer.obj.myFunction();
```